# Передача параметров по значению

Tags: 1с

Ясного неба!

Ситуация такая: Есть массив. Передаю его в процедуру по значению. Работаю внутри процедуры якобы с копией массива, но в итоге оказывается, что все равно передается ссылка на него, и значение передаваемого массива меняется.

часть кода в процедуре:

```
Процедура ЗаполнитьДаты(Периоды, Знач МойМассив, КолонкаНачала, КолонкаКонца) 
...
Пока Дата(МойМассив[0] + " 00:00:00") < ПерваяДатаЛиста  Цикл
  МойМассив.Удалить(0);
  Если МойМассив.Количество() = 0 Тогда
    прервать;
  КонецЕсли;  
КонецЦикла;
...
КонецПроцедуры;
```

Что я делаю не так, и как правильно это сделать?

---

Интересно, что даже если я делаю так:

```
Массив1 = Массив2;
Массив1.Удалить(0);
```

Массив2 изменится. Напрашивается вопрос - как при обычном присваивании копировать значение, а не ссылку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Передача параметра по значению не копирует объект. Объект остается тот же. Вызывая методы в процедуре, обращение идет к методам исходного объекта. Вот если бы в процедуре было бы `МойМассив = Новый Массив()`, тогда изменения исходного объекта не было бы.

Аналог из паскаля:

```
procedure ClearStringListValue(SL: TStringList);//По значению
begin
 SL.Clear;
end;

procedure ClearStringListLink(var SL: TStringList);//По ссылке
begin
 SL.Clear;
end;
```

и там и там SL очистится.
Передача по значению будет видна тут:

```
procedure ClearStringListValue(SL: TStringList);//По значению
begin
 SL:=TStringList.Create;
 SL.Add('by value');
end;//Значение не изменится

procedure ClearStringListLink(var SL: TStringList);//По ссылке
begin
 SL:=TStringList.Create;
 SL.Add('by link');
end;//Будет новый стринглист
```

Соответственно, чтоб изменения не было, нужно вручную копировать объект. Для массива нету метода копирования, ну знач самостоятельно в цикле...

ЗЫ [Передача параметров по ссылке и по значению при вызове процедур и функций](http://pro1c.org.ua/index.php?showtopic=184)

Comment: Это новации 1С? В остальных случаях передача параметра по значению создаёт копию объекта (если нужно) для того, чтобы исходный объект не менялся.

Comment: @alexlz я же привел пример из паскаля/дельфей. Конструктора копирования как в плюсах нету, передача параметра по значению копирует ссылку, а не объект.  
В javascript'е тоже ведь объекты по ссылке передаются, только примитивные типы по значению.  
Так вот, если нужна копия объекта копируйте его в функции сами.  

Такова идеология, и не в 1с ее придумали, по крайней мере ничего сверхъестественного в этом нету, в 1с других причуд хватает :)

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь - 1С это лицензированный VBA, который патриотично перевели на русский язык

Comment: Так в delphi при передаче параметров по значению копия не создаётся? Как интересно. "А мужики-то и не знают" (из рекламы). А что же тогда SL в Вашем примере? И её атрибуты Вы можете менять, и в вызывающей программе эти изменения видны будут? Ух как. Бедный Н. Вирт, чего сотворили в его паскалем.

Кстати, из доки по Вашей ссылке: " Внутри вызываемой процедуры ОбработатьТаблицу() создается новый экземпляр таблицы значений, в который добавляется три строки. Это никак не влияет на состояние таблицы значений Тз, переданной в качестве фактического параметра при вызове процедуры ОбработатьТаблицу()"

Comment: @alexlz, не вижу причин для вашего сарказма. при передаче параметра по значению будет создана копия ссылки. "копия ссылки" от "копия объекта" отличайте просто.

Comment: Т.е. TStringList -- это указатель? И дальше всё как в старом добром C? Бедный Вирт.

Comment: именно. A pointer, class, class-reference, or procedure-pointer parameter is passed as a 32-bit pointer. и все тут.

Comment: Тут ещё проблемы терминологии на русском. "Передача параметра по значению не копирует объект". Если объект -- целое, вещественное и запись (record), то всё нормально. Копируются. Если идут ооп-объедки, то указатель -- он и в java указатель. Ясности и строгости паскаля в дельфах нет и не будет, поэтому такие вещи желательно как-то оговаривать. Я понимаю, что настоящий дельфин не назовёт структуру (record) объектом, так ведь не все же "настоящие дельфины"...

Comment: начиная с 2006 дельфы record стал объектом у него появились свойства, методы, конструктор, правда нету виртуальных методов и деструктора, вполне себе объект. а вот передача по значению таки копирует весь record. ну и еще там отличия есть некоторые, в доках написано.